# js file loaded only if included twice

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

In jsp I have strange behavior.If I include js file once, it is not loaded, but if I include it twice, all work properly.

In `spring-conf.xml`:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>
```

In jsp I include js like this:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/js/script.js" />" ></script>
```

If I copy it below , all right. What is the cause of it?

Comment: Are you getting error in console? What script are you loading?

Comment: no I haven't error. I loading my simple file with only 1 json request function, and function is correct. Before it I loaded jquery and it correct work.

Comment: yes, but I loaded it after jquery , and it's local file...

Comment: hm...now I try loaded css file instead js, and it's doesn't work too

Comment: <head>
        <title>Game</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/css/game.css"/>"/>
        <script src="<c:url value="/js/script.js" />" ></script>
    </head>

Comment: So there is a function that loads JSON on load and sets it to some DOM element. Try loading this file after body tag in HTML  or call this function on `$(document).ready()`

Comment: oh sorry I don't understand how edit it...

Comment: Put these script tags at thye bottom of your page. Your script is loading before your DOM is rendered and hence you are getting issues

Comment: I resolve problem! I replace  <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" />  to <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" ></script> and all begin work properly!